# Groovy documentation on `times` iterator

Tags: gradle, groovy

Where can I find the documentation on this type of `4.times` iterator?

```
4.times { counter ->
    tasks.register("task$counter") {
        doLast {
            println "I'm task number $counter"
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('task0') { dependsOn('task2', 'task3') }
```

I can't seem to find it in the [docs](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_looping_structures) yet examples using it are all over the place.

[source of code](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:dynamic_tasks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Groovy JDK API Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) for [`Number.times(Closure closure)`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#times(groovy.lang.Closure)):

> Executes the closure this many times, starting from zero. The current index is passed to the closure each time. Example:
>
> ```
> 10.times {
>   println it
> }
> ```
>
> Prints the numbers 0 through 9.
>
> **Parameters:**
> `closure` - the closure to call a number of times
>
> **Since:**
> 1.0

It is a method added by Groovy to the `java.lang.Number` class.

Comment: Great! Can you expand on how the groovy docs I linked and the groovy jdk docs are connected? I'm trying to understand how groovy, this "gdk" and java in general are intertwined. From my novice perspective, I can't tell what is coming from where. The `Number.times` doc appears in the `java.lang` class, but this `times` method does not appear in the [Java API itself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html).

Comment: @topher217 It doesn't appear in the Java API, Because it's not a Java API method. It is a "method added to the JDK to make it more groovy". As I already said in the answer, the method is added by Groovy. --- Go to the [Groovy documentation page](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html). This is where you clicked on "Semantics" in the "Language Specification" section to get the link in the question. Instead, click the second link in the "API documentation" called "The Groovy Development Kit enhancements". Read the first line.